# How to prevent multiple time click on anchor tag in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created sharing functionality it will be work but

```js
//HERE WE CREATE THE CONTOLLER FOR SHARING
$scope.selectedSharedBuyerKeyList     = [];
$scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList  = [];
$scope.productObjectForShareModal     = [];

$scope.getConnectedSharedUser         = function(product) {
$scope.productObjectForShareModal = product;
var data = {
  productKeyId : $scope.productObjectForShareModal.keyId
}

//Call the getSharedUserList function for get the detail of the shared connectedUsers
SellerDashboardService.getSharedUserList(function(response) {    
    if(response != null) {
      if (response.data.isProduct) {
        $scope.selectedSharedBuyerKeyList = response.data.sellerProductsDto;

        // Obtaining user object..
        $scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList = [];
        for(var selectedSharedBuyerKey of $scope.selectedSharedBuyerKeyList) {
          var data = selectedSharedBuyerKey;
          //call the getBuyerInShared for get the list of the objects 
          SellerDashboardService.getBuyerInShared(function(response) {
            if(response != null) {
              if (response.data.isbuyer) {
                var buyerObject = response.data.isbuyer;
                $scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList.push(buyerObject);
              }
            }
          },data);
        }
      }
    }
},data);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="fa fa fa-group btn btn-xs pull-left bg-color-d4"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#groupModal" 
  ng-click="getConnectedSharedUser(productDBList)">
</a>
```

list is repeated after multiple time click on the a tag and user list is repeated again and again.so tell me how to resolve the repeatation problem?

Comment: Disable the button after the first click

Comment: sir i am using panel not a button and how to disable it?

Comment: Try my answer below, it should work for panel also

Comment: ok sir i will try

Comment: sir i am using this but list is repeated again?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList  = [];
$scope.productObjectForShareModal     = [];

$scope.cliked=false ///set click to false



$scope.getConnectedSharedUser         = function(product) {
$scope.productObjectForShareModal = product;
var data = {
  productKeyId : $scope.productObjectForShareModal.keyId
}

//Call the getSharedUserList function for get the detail of the shared connectedUsers
SellerDashboardService.getSharedUserList(function(response) {               
$scope.clicked =true;  ///set it back to true
    if(response != null) {
      if (response.data.isProduct) {
        $scope.selectedSharedBuyerKeyList = response.data.sellerProductsDto;

        // Obtaining user object..
        $scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList = [];
        for(var selectedSharedBuyerKey of $scope.selectedSharedBuyerKeyList) {
          var data = selectedSharedBuyerKey;
          //call the getBuyerInShared for get the list of the objects 
          SellerDashboardService.getBuyerInShared(function(response) {
            if(response != null) {
              if (response.data.isbuyer) {
                var buyerObject = response.data.isbuyer;
                $scope.selectedSharedBuyerObjectList.push(buyerObject);
              }
            }
          },data);
        }
      }
    }
},data);
}



<a href="#" class="fa fa fa-group btn btn-xs pull-left bg-color-d4"
    data-toggle="modal" ng-disabled="cliked" data-target="#groupModal" 
  ng-click="getConnectedSharedUser(productDBList)">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did in angular 2 is I have Disabled the button on the first click.

E.g.

```
<button (click)="someFunction()" [disabled]="disableButton"></button>
someFunction() {
      disableButton = true;
}
```

**Note**: Syntax would be different in your case but logic will be same.
I hope this will help.